# Log progress with salt stack

Tags: vagrant, salt-stack

When running saltstack in vagrant, saltstack does not log tasks that it is performing, during the process. It does print the report later. But if the task takes a lot of time and you are waiting for it to complete this can be annoying.

Here is my vagrant file:

```rb
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.synced_folder "salt/roots/", "/srv/salt/"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  config.vm.provision :salt do |salt|
    salt.minion_config = "salt/minion.yml"
    salt.run_highstate = true
    salt.colorize = true
    # salt.log_level = 'warning'
    end
end
```

How do I tell saltstack to log tasks as they're being performed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the minion config file template called out in that vagrantfile (and in the folder with your vagrantfile) 'salt/minion.yml' file and add this line to it:

```
log_level: warning
```

More info:

http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/configuration/logging/index.html